# 複数のjpegファイルを一つのpdfファイルに変換したい

Tags: python, pdf

複数のjpegファイルが入ったフォルダを指定して，一つのpdfファイルに変換したいと思い，以下のようなコードをPythonで書いてみたのですが，フォルダの中の一つのjpegファイルだけしかpdfに変換されませんでした.
どこが間違っているかご指摘頂けるとありがたいです.

```
import img2pdf,os
from PIL import Image
base_Image = r"jpegが入っているファイルのパス" 
Create_pdf = r"できたpdfを入れたい場所のパス"
os.chdir(base_Image)
path = "./"
files = os.listdir(path)
pdf_name = Create_pdf + "\\" + "converted" + ".pdf"
for i in files:
    if i.endswith(".jpeg"):
        Image_Name = i
        img = Image.open(Image_Name)
        cov_pdf = img2pdf.convert(Image_Name)
        file = open(pdf_name , "wb")
        file.write(cov_pdf)
        img.close()
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

`file = open(pdf_name , "wb")` の処理で一枚ずつ画像を読み込む度にpdfを**新規作成**し直しているのが原因で、最後に読み込んだ画像のみを含むpdfファイルができているようです。

下記のサンプルコードで複数画像を1つのpdfにまとめたファイル作成できます。(python 3.6.1で確認)

**サンプルコード**

```
import img2pdf
import os
import re
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path

base_Image = r"jpegが入っているファイルのパス" 
Create_pdf = r"できたpdfを入れたい場所のパス" 

path = Path(base_Image)
images = sorted([str(p) for p in path.glob('**/*') if re.search('/*\.(jpg|jpeg)', str(p), re.IGNORECASE)])
pdf_name = os.path.join(Create_pdf, "converted.pdf")

with open(pdf_name , "wb") as f:
    f.write(img2pdf.convert(images))
```